# Azure ad b2c: Can not access backend in with custom policy configured

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, single-page-application, azure-ad-b2c

I can follow the [demo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-single-page-app-webapi?tabs=applications) here to have single page application in client side and a nodejs application in backend running correctly. Based on the document, I need to create two apps. one is ***webapi1*** app, for nodejs backend, another is ***webapp1*** for single page application.

While now I want to use custom policy, so based on the document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-get-started?tabs=app-reg-preview) I have to create another two apps: **IdentityExperienceFramework** and **ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework**.  After that I can login successfully and get access token, but any http request with token to backend will return 401.

I want to know what is the right way to have custom policy and have a protected backend resource.  Do I really need 4 apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IdentityExperienceFramework and ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework are only used by the policies themselves to sign the user in.
They don't matter for your other apps basically, but they need to exist.
You'd specify your front-end app client id as the client_id when logging in, and request tokens for your API app using its scopes.

Comment: Hi, juunas. Thanks for you reply. Actually I'm working on a production environment with a frontend app and .net backend. I have configured the client_id you mentioned, front-end can get access token from scope, and it can send request successfully, whilte it happens when I use User Flow. When I change to custom policy, I can still get access token using scope, while request to backend will return 401.  I'm confused about this.

Comment: Have you inspected the tokens at e.g. https://jwt.ms? Check what the difference is. Your Authority in API should also include the policy id, make sure to update that.

Comment: What library protects the backend? Provide code snippets of the config. Provide a copy of the decoded access token.

Comment: Yes, you're right, the problem is the new policy name is not correctly in API backend. Thanks, @juunas